# Gulp + Sourcemaps + PostCSS(Autoprefixer + Minification via CSSnano)

Tags: build, gulp, postcss, autoprefixer, gulp-sourcemaps

Basically, I want sourcemaps available to my unminified and minifies flavors of my site.css file. I'd like my end result to be:

- site.css
- site.min.css
- **site.css.map**
- site.css.min.map

Currently, I only get:

- site.css
- site.min.css
- site.css.min.map

I know my gulp script is wrong, but I don't know how to fix it.  I need sourcemaps to write a sourcemap to site.css before site.min.css gets created. HALP!
and Thank you

```js
gulp.task('scss', gulp.series('bootstrap:scss', function compileScss() {
 return gulp.src(['./site/assets/scss/*.scss'])
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe(sass.sync({
   outputStyle: 'expanded'
  }).on('error', sass.logError))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./site/dist/css'))  // outputs site.css
  .pipe(postcss([autoprefixer(), cssnano()
  ]))
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
  .pipe(rename({
   suffix: '.min'
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./site/dist/css'))  //outputs site.min.css
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need sourcemaps for your unminified version, i would introduce a NODE_ENV for doing minification and sourcemaps, then use [gulp-if](https://github.com/robrich/gulp-if) to see if you're in development or production environment

Alternatively you could have separate build and dev tasks.

Using `process.env.NODE_ENV` means you can use them in `postcss.config.js` files etc. too

I found [this](https://css-tricks.com/gulp-for-wordpress-initial-setup/) really good because it shows you how you can use a gulp.babel.js file with Gulp 4. I was using 3.9.1 being reluctant to upgrade until this week but this helped immensely with understanding the changes from v3>4.